Protagonist with plant power I can't remember the name of the original story
I read a kingdom building novel a few years ago and the protagonist has plant-based powers.
I found the unfinished translation with only 40 chapters called: Plant Lord: Starting with 10000 time increase.
But I remember that the original novel has many more chapters, but I can't find the original title or any other place with the translation of the novel.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Do you recall where you found it?  The names of any of the characters?

I read it about 4 to 5 years ago. I don't remember the names of the characters. But in the translation I found, the protagonist's name is Lin Sen.

I mean it's possible to find it all over the place (webnovel, wuxiaworld, etc.) by googling the name, but there's no information about an original.  If there really was an original.  It sounds really bad, are you sure you want to find more?

https://www.webnovel.com/book/plant-lord-starting-with-10-000-times-increase_24111924506253205

I found it!!!!! I knew I wasn't crazy!!! Hahaha. My memory didn't betray me hahahaha.

https://www.fanmtl.com/novel/lord-of-plants-speed-%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bup-time-by-100-times-at-the-start.html
